# Unable to calculate accuracy after performing Train, Test and Validation splits

Tags: r, machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

I am using the classic `iris` dataset and trying to learn the Knn algorithm for different values of `k`. I perform a `train-test-validation` split to generate 3 partitions. After this, I use the train and test to fit a knn classifier. But I get an error after splitting.

My approach

```
spec = c(train = .5, test = .25, validate = .25)

byparts = sample(cut(
  seq(nrow(iris)), 
  nrow(iris)*cumsum(c(0,spec)),
  labels = names(spec)
))

res = split(iris, byparts)

addmargins(prop.table(table(byparts)))

#Model fit
library(class)
train_feat <- res$train[,1:4] 
test_feat <- res$test[,1:4]

set.seed(1)
train_pred <- knn(train_feat, train_feat, res$train["Species"], k=1)
train_acc <- mean(train_pred == res$train["Species"])

set.seed(1)
test_pred <- knn(train_feat, test_feat, res$train["Species"], k=1)
test_acc <- mean(valid_pred == res$test["Species"])

cat('Training Accuracy:   ', train_acc, '\n',
    'Validation Accuracy: ', valid_acc, sep='')
```

It says the `train` and `class` have different lengths

```
Error in knn(train_feat, train_feat, res$train["Species"], k = 1) : 
  'train' and 'class' have different lengths
```

Is this due to the way how I split the partition or should I re-split it again? Would like to know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not print the lengths of these and debug?

Comment: I pretty much tried but cannot proceed. Stuck for hour on this issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if we, too, could see the lengths that were printed.

Comment: > ```length(train_feat)
[1] 4
> length(res$train["Species"])
[1] 1
```

Comment: I tried this approach earlier but there it worked well with no issues. It's only here, not sure whether due to the 3-split that I made or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the type of your data, based on what happens inside the `knn` function.

```r
train_targets = as.matrix(res$train["Species"])  # Fixes the length calculation.
train_pred = knn(train_feat, train_feat, train_targets, k=1)
train_acc = mean(train_pred == train_targets)
```

You should make a similar adjustment for the test and validation sets.

---

Why did this happen? Check the source code of `knn` by printing `knn` in your R interpreter. It checks whether the lengths match, according to `length`. `length(res$train["Species"])` is 1, even though `dim(res$train["Species"])` is 75×1. When you convert it to a matrix with `as.matrix`, the issue goes away.

Comment: appreciate your precious time in debugging this issue.  I pretty much now understand that there are lot many things internally happening when we do data transformation :)